# Syntax in function_name()()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component

The last line in the example code

```
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

withStyles API says

*withStyles(styles, [options]) => higher-order component*
which does not contain two continuous bracketed components.

What syntax is used in withStyles()()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) or [Function Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) depending on the context (both are essentially same concept, just viewed differently).

In plain JavaScript, `func()()` is basically taking the output of one function and passing it to another.

In React and functional programming, this pattern is used to compose different functions into a pipeline of sorts (since React components are essentially just JavaScript functions).